# Create Preferences dialog in GTK

Tags: c, grid, gtk, gtk3

Im new to gtk+ 3 and I want to create for my app, Preferences dialog. Don't use glade only C.

My questions is how create space between green line and red line using gtk_grid.
Tanks for any help

[image]

Align "Start playing files..." check box at 20 relative to "Playback" label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the GtkGrid documentation says:

> GtkGrid is a container which arranges its child widgets in rows and
>   columns. It is a very similar to GtkTable and GtkBox, but it
>   consistently uses GtkWidget's "margin" and "expand" properties instead
>   of custom child properties, and it fully supports height-for-width
>   geometry management.

So you set the margin not on the grid, but on each widget inside the grid, by using GtkWidget's `margin`, `margin-bottom`, `margin-top`, `margin-left` or `margin-right` properties.

There's [more on GtkGrid](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch29s03.html) about that in the GTK documentation

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`GtkAlignment` Widget](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkAlignment) - provides horzontal alignment, vertical alignment  , padding (all 4 directions) (I guess this is what you are looking for), and some others